# Update composto

Tags: sql, sql-update

Eu tenho uma tabela `pessoas` onde, tenho vários campos referentes ao cadastro da pessoa, Um destes campos é o `PES_NUMERO`, que nada mais é que o código da pessoa no sistema, pois bem, tenho um outro campo chamado `EST_NUMERO`, onde informo a qual estrutura a pessoa pertence.

Preciso atualizar este `EST_NUMERO` de acordo com uma planilha onde tenho o número da matrícula.

Abaixo o código que escrevi para que possam entender melhor

```
USE RBACESSO_V100
GO
UPDATE PESSOAS 
SET EST_NUMERO = 100 -- Numero do código da estrutura que a pessoa deve receber.
WHERE PES_NUMERO = 1222244 -- Numero da matricula da pessoa a ser atualizada.
```

O comando `WHERE` eu informo a condição para o `update`, só que preciso de informar ali vários números de matricula é não apenas um pois tenho cerca de 2063 registros para atualizar, como faço para colocar um espécie de condição ali para pegar todas as matrículas, algo tipo um `and`?

Comment: Uma maneira seria essa:` WHERE PES_NUMERO IN ( A,B,C,D,E,F,G)`

Comment: Talvez ajude se colocar a *tag* odo banco de dados que está usando.

Comment: Como isso vai ser feito? ou seja, como você esta passando isso para o banco de dados?

Comment: Então ate então estou informando manualmente no banco de dados, ou sejá estou digitando o cod da matricula manualmente

Comment: existe uma outra forma de trazer isso para o banco de maneira mais pratica ??

Comment: O código EST_NUMERO é oriundo da planilha? Ou é fixo?

Comment: Não este código é fixo o mesmo esta contido em outra tabela neste mesmo banco onde é feito uma especie de cadastro de estrutura da empresa !

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira simples:

```
where pes_numero in ( a,b,c,d,e )
```

ou

```
 where pes_numero in ( select matricula from tabela_matricula where 
     condicao )
```

Comment: Perfeito, acho que assim vai funcionar, como não tenho conhecimento na linguagem estava com sintaxe incorreta, não estava usando o IN

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!!!!

Comment: Caro Reginaldo, sua resposta é válida sim, dependendo do contexto. Porém notei que o Gustavo informou que seriam 2063 registros e para cláusulas IN (ao menos em postgreSQL tenho certeza) há um limite de 1000 condições caso sejam informadas uma a uma (sem uma subconsulta). Como não foi informado o SGBD essa resposta pode ser válida ou não.

Comment: Foi por isso que coloquei uma segunda opção. Com a segunda opção funciona perfeitamente, independente do numero de registros.

Comment: Então tenho que me atentar a essa quantidade de registros, Vou tentar montar aqui com a segunda opção do Reginaldo, é realizar os testes